# Improving PHP Performance of Multiple RSS Feed Requests?

Tags: php, html, performance, mobile, rss

I'm working on a little mobile app version of www.sciencedaily.com. Just a little side project.

I'm using RSS_PHP to grab the XML feeds, and the code I have (which works great) looks like this before the DOCTYPE:

```
require_once '_/rss_php.php';

$featuredRSS = new rss_php;
$healthMedRSS = new rss_php;
$mindBrainRSS = new rss_php;
$plantsAnimalsRSS = new rss_php;
$earthClimateRSS = new rss_php;
$spaceTimeRSS = new rss_php;
$matterEnergyRSS = new rss_php;
$compMathRSS = new rss_php;
$archaeoRSS = new rss_php;

$featuredRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/top_news/top_science.xml');
$healthMedRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/health_medicine.xml');
$mindBrainRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/mind_brain.xml');
$plantsAnimalsRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/plants_animals.xml');
$earthClimateRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/earth_climate.xml');
$spaceTimeRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/space_time.xml');
$matterEnergyRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/matter_energy.xml');
$compMathRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/computers_math.xml');
$archaeoRSS->load('http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/fossils_ruins.xml');

$featuredItems = $featuredRSS->getItems();
$healthMedItems = $healthMedRSS->getItems();
$mindBrainItems = $mindBrainRSS->getItems();
$plantsAnimalsItems = $plantsAnimalsRSS->getItems();
$earthClimateItems = $earthClimateRSS->getItems();
$spaceTimeItems = $spaceTimeRSS->getItems();
$matterEnergyItems = $matterEnergyRSS->getItems();
$compMathItems = $compMathRSS->getItems();
$archaeoItems = $archaeoRSS->getItems();
```

Then, in the content, I'm echoing out results by using classic stuff like

```
foreach($items as $item) {

    echo $item['title'];
}
etc...
```

Like I said, everything works really well. But it's *slow* as hell. I know there's going to be a limit to the speed of the app, as it has to grab the feeds, but there's no caching ability with RSS_PHP like there is with SimplePie.

Any ideas on improving the speed? Maybe loading the Featured stuff first then everything else?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you have to load all of the feeds at once? You could just defer loading until whenever the user requests them, or put a limit on the amount each feed initially provides. Then, when you need to update the list, you can just make an AJAX request to your server, and redraw your UI as needed. Alternatively, you could still load everything initially, but by using AJAX, ie: remove the aforementioned lazy loading.

Comment: If this is working, it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't know the api here, but do those items load serially, or in parallel? If healthMed doesn't start it's work until featuredItems finishes, what you want is to spawn multiple threads to handle this. Not too easy in PHP.

Comment: @josh I can't figure out how to defer the loading. I've set numerical limits but will play with AJAX.

Comment: @niko, it's not really working. I can some of the URLS to load, but the site will time out so this is actually necessary to get the app to work correctly.

Comment: And @Nathaniel-Ford, they're loading serially. The RSS_PHP api isn't really offering different loading abilities, it's pretty much purely just an rss/xml parser. I don't know how to run multiple threads, which is what brought me here. It is quite confusing, it seems, with PHP.

Answer (score 5):

Use [CURL library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). There is option for multi request at same time. All request will run at the same time parallel. Check this link for example and tutorial. [php curl parallel requests](http://www.somacon.com/p537.php)

**Update**

Look for documentation about [php_rss](http://rssphp.net/documentation/#RSS_PHP.Properties). Use

```
$testRSS->loadRSS($res); //$Res is string data from Curl instead of url
```

Comment: This is a great way to grab the URLs, but I can't pass it into RSS_PHP like so: https://gist.github.com/2362136

Comment: Thanks @savarov. I've tried messing with loadRSS and loadXML before, no cigar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to attempt to get you started on using threads. I'm using a reduced number of rss feeds for clarity's sake.

```
require_once '_/rss_php.php';

public class loadFeeds(){

private int workers = 0;

private function launchWorker(&$feed, $url) {//NOTE: pass by reference!
  $pid = pcntl_fork();
  switch ($pid) {
  case -1: // fork failed
    $this->clog("ERROR: Worker fork failure. Running inline.");
    $feed->load($url);
    break;
  case 0: // child fork
    $feed->load($url));
    break;
  default: // parent fork?
    $this->workers++;
    echo "$this->workers launched.\n";
    break;
}

public function load() {
  $featuredRSS = new rss_php;
  $healthMedRSS = new rss_php;
  $mindBrainRSS = new rss_php;

  //Start some threads
  launchWorker($featuredRSS, 'http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/top_news/top_science.xml');
  launchWorker($healthMedRSS, 'http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/top_news/top_science.xml');
  launchWorker($mindBrainRSS, 'http://www.sciencedaily.com/rss/top_news/top_science.xml');

  $status = 0;
  while ($this->workers > 0) {//wait until all workers are done.
    while ($pid = pcntl_wait($status, WNOHANG OR WUNTRACED)) {//wait for a thread to report
      if ($pid > 0) { // if we have a valid pid 
        $this->workers--;//recover worker
      }
    }
  }

  $featuredItems = $featuredRSS->getItems();
  $healthMedItems = $healthMedRSS->getItems();
  $mindBrainItems = $mindBrainRSS->getItems();
}
```

Mind you, I haven't tested this, because I'm not presently set up to, but it gives you the main components. If you run into problems, you can spawn additional questions here.

Comment: great input, but it unfortunately doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Implement some form of caching, this will help in any case.
- Maybe consider to use some ajax, the page will load fast, and the RSS
  will be shown one by one as soon as they are in. You might also be
  able to run several calls simmulaniously.

Answer (score 0):

Implement caching server side, here is a script I created a few years back (correct as needed):

**rss-fetch.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
#------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# This script will run via CRONTAB and fetch RSS feeds from the
# urls.txt file, which can be used internally.  This way we minimize
# the number of requests externally for data.
#
# - created by Jakub - March 26 2008
#
#------------------------------------------------------------------

basedir=/htdocs/RSS
storedir=/htdocs/RSS/read/
sourcefile=/htdocs/RSS/urls.txt

#------------------------------------------------------------------
# Read the URLS.TXT file to get the URL/filename
#
# Formatted:
# http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot/slashdot.xml
# ^- URL                    ^- filename to save as

for s in `cat "$sourcefile"`; 
    do  
        geturl=`dirname $s`;
        filename=`basename $s`;
        wget -qN $geturl -pO "$storedir"$filename;
done;

#------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then pull the local rss feeds into your PHP to parse, your delay is in fetching external sources.

If you set the script above on a CRON, it will fetch at whatever frequency you desire.
Enjoy!

Comment: hey, thanks for the input. This looks great, but I'm not sure how I'd grab that data and then put it into my main index.php file. Thank you though!

Comment: You would stick the links you need into the `urls.txt` file I defined, change the `basedir` & `storedir` to your location where you can call your RSS feeds. You are basically saving them locally (and php will open the local files to read and display without you having to remote fetch them each time).

Comment: Right, but there isn't literally a URL, local or remote, for me to put into `$testRSS->load('');`. You know what mean?

Comment: @ggwicz, well modify your RSS script to grab the file, you're not going to fix this otherwise, just load using something like `file()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score -1):

According to [the documentation](http://rssphp.net/documentation/#RSS_PHP.load), it can load data from a local URI as well - why don't you fetch the remote feeds in a separate script, say, every 15 minutes, and load only the local versions here? It would reduce the load on the remote server *and* reduce your bandwidth usage.

Comment: Why the downvote, it's a stellar suggestion (to a seemingly very lazy OP)